# knockout optional validation with max-size and custom validator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, knockout.js

I have one VM which has multiple forms with all validation. To support multiple forms i think i have to implement knockout optional validation.
There are many validations in my forms. Like `maxLength` , `minlength` ,`required` and one custom validation.

The validations looks like this

```
@password = ko.observable("").extend({ required: true, minLength: 5})
@current_password = ko.observable().extend({
      validation: { validator: @mustEqual, message: 'Passwords do not match.', params: @password }
    })
```

Now, to make the above validation optional with `isLoggedIn` i use this

```
@password  = ko.observable().extend
  required:
    onlyIf: () =>
      !@isLoggedIn()
```

but it only works for `required` . i also want it for `minLength` and for `custom validator` . How to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

onlyIf can be used with all validators, like this (fiddle, forked from github examples: http://jsfiddle.net/LYP5u/25/):

```
 self.testField = ko.observable(5).extend({
        max:{
            onlyIf:function() { return self.country() === 'US'},
            params:5
        }
    });
```

Example from validation source: https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/blob/master/Src/api.js#L225

Conditional validation docs: https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Conditional-Validation-with-onlyIf-parameter

Maybe we should talk to one of the maintainers to make this more clear in the manual, perhaps add some examples with onlyIf to this page https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Native-Rules